# Verifyer status shoutcast

Tags: php, ajax, shoutcast

I was using shoutcast 1.9.8 and check the status with the following code:

```
$status_streaming = status_streaming($dados_servidor["ip"],$dados_stm["porta"]);

if($status_streaming == "ligado") {

mysql_query("Update streamings set pid='".$resultado."' where codigo = '".$dados_stm["codigo"]."'");

echo "<span class='texto_status_sucesso'>Oi <strong>".$dados_stm["identificacao"]."</strong>, sua r&aacute;dio foi iniciada.</span><br /><br/><a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='status_streaming(\"".$dados_stm["porta"]."\");document.getElementById(\"log-sistema-fundo\").style.display = \"none\";document.getElementById(\"log-sistema\").style.display = \"none\";'></a>";

} else {
echo "<span class='texto_status_erro'>N&atilde;o foi poss&iacute;vel ligar sua emissora <strong>".$dados_stm["identificacao"]."</strong>,<br><strong>Motivo:</strong>Desconhecido (contate a CasCast).</span>";
}

} else {
echo "<span class='texto_status_erro'>N&atilde;o foi poss&iacute;vel a emissora <br><strong>Motivo:</strong>".$resultado."</span>";
}

} else {
echo "<span class='texto_status_erro'>A R&aacute;dio <strong>".$dados_stm["identificacao"]."</strong> j&aacute; esta acionada.</span>";
}

exit();
```

After upgrading to v2.0 shoutcast the verification code does not work!
I guess it's because the ip and port uses.

```
shoutcast v1 ip:port

shoutcast v2 ip:port/index.html
```

How do I update my code to detect on and off shoutcast v2?

Thanks!

function ajax:

```
function status_streaming( porta ) {

  document.getElementById( porta ).innerHTML = "<img src='http://"+get_host()+"/admin/img/spinner.gif' />";

  var http = new Ajax();
  http.open("GET", "/admin/funcoes-ajax/status_streaming/"+porta , true);
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {

  if(http.readyState == 4) {

    resultado = http.responseText;

    if(resultado == "ligado") {

    document.getElementById( porta ).innerHTML = "Ligado";
    document.getElementById( porta ).className = "texto_status_streaming_online";

    } else if(resultado == "ligado-autodj") {

    document.getElementById( porta ).innerHTML = "AutoDJ";
    document.getElementById( porta ).className = "texto_status_streaming_online";

    } else if(resultado == "ligado-relay") {

    document.getElementById( porta ).innerHTML = "Relay";
    document.getElementById( porta ).className = "texto_status_streaming_online";

    } else if(resultado == "desligado") {

    document.getElementById( porta ).innerHTML = "Desligado";
    document.getElementById( porta ).className = "texto_status_streaming_offline";

    } else {

    document.getElementById( porta ).innerHTML = "Erro";
    document.getElementById( porta ).className = "texto_status_streaming_offline";

    }

  }

  }
  http.send(null);
  delete http;
}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to detect whether or not the station is running?  If so, I suggest checking for stream data so that your code will work on all streaming servers, and not just SHOUTcast.  This would also allow you to use the same code for SHOUTcast 1.x and 2.x.

Comment: Thanks! question solved!